# Avoiding duplicated links with branch.io sdk

Tags: android, ios, deep-linking, branch.io

We have implemented the Branch.IO in our app and is working great. We can generate `deeplinks` and get data on both Platform, IOS, and Android.

But we have a doubt about duplicated links.

See, we have generated links on IOS and after that,  generated another link with the same **canonical_identifier** on Android.

What we expected is that Branch.io should return the same Url, but this didn't happen.

We are trying to do this to avoid duplicated entries and, maybe, have more control about links.

Below, the data from both generated links maybe can help:

**Generated on Android :**

```
 "~creation_source":2,
  "$og_title":"Casamento <3",
  "$identity_id":517787482772223550,
  "~feature":"Share",
  "source":"android",
  "$og_description":"Eder Baldrighi e Angelina Jolie - 04/07/2018",
  "$one_time_use":false,
  "$canonical_identifier":"giftlist+11",
  "$publicly_indexable":"true",
  "~id":"518054928284095986",
  "type":"giftlist",
  "+url":"XXXXXX.test-app.link/ODzOUGnRqM",
  "value":"11"
```

**Generated on IOS:**

```
  "$locally_indexable":true,
  "~creation_source":3,
  "$og_title":"Casamento <3",
  "custom_data":"yes",
  "$identity_id":517745509809925500,
  "$og_description":"Eder Baldrighi e Angelina Jolie - 04/07/2018",
  "$one_time_use":false,
  "$canonical_identifier":"giftlist+11",
  "$exp_date":0,
  "$publicly_indexable":true,
  "~id":"518045049171363141",
  "type":"giftlist",
  "+url":"XXXXXX.test-app.link/HkkcqLzOqM",
  "value":"11"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aaron from [Branch](https://branch.io/) here! By design, we do not merge link URLs based on link data alone like `$canonical_identifier`s. Any link generated via the [SDK](https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/ios/), [API](https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/api/), or [Dashboard](https://dashboard.branch.io/) that is created with our v1/url endpoint will generate a new link URL unless you are [updating a link](https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/api/#link-update).

Analytics, however, will be unified on the Branch dashboard. Content links, for example, that we detect is the same will show up in the [Content Analytics](https://dashboard.branch.io/content) page merged into one piece of content based on link data like `$canonical_identifier`. [Source Analytics](https://dashboard.branch.io/sources) will merge links based on analytic tags like `~channel`, `~campaign`, & `~tags`.

Comment: Thank you ! We also have talk with Neil from Branch.IO. As you said, this is the expected behavior  : To create different links for different devices/clients . Best Regards.